# Sencha Touch Uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, syntax-error

I have recently began to check out Sencha Touch.  In following there tutorials I have ran into some issues that I cannot seem to resolve.

Some of the basic code in app.js that is provided from sencha runs fine.  Others seem to get errors.  For Example:

```
new Ext.application({
name: "NotesApp",
launch: function() {
        console.log("App Launch");
    }
});
```

With this I get an: Uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function

If I rewrite the code without new at the beginning like:

```
Ext.application({
name: "NotesApp",
launch: function() {
        console.log("App Launch");
    }
});
```

I get "Uncaught typeError: Object #  has no method 'application'"

The second way is what I see all over the place when looking up sencha but it seems to be gining me issues.  Can any one help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Ext.Application has a capital A. Remember that Javascript is case sensitive.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Application