# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I am new in sencha touch. So I am just try the code from [this article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-simple-application-sencha-touch).
The problem is when i run  this code  it gives this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  (TouchStart.js:2)

`TouchStart.js :`

```
// JavaScript Document
new Ext.Application({
name: 'Chat',
launch: function() {
var hello = new Ext.Container({
fullscreen: true,
html: '<div id="hello">Hello World</div>'
  });

this.viewport = hello;
  }
});
```

I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888143/sencha-touch-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function)  but not found solution. so what is the problem?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
// JavaScript Document
new Ext.Application({
name: 'Chat',
launch: function() {
var hello = new Ext.Container({
fullscreen: true,
html: '<div id="hello">Hello World</div>'
  });

Ext.Application.viewport = hello;
  }
});
```

Comment: it is the problem in `sencha-touch.js` file, i replace it. and then this error occured `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setConfig' of undefined` and then your answer is work for me. so Thank you very much for your answer.